# Int into label SpriteKit SKView, hl

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, integer, sklabelnode

I just want to know if is it possible to make a label or anything else who will be a integer and to display it to my gameview.

```
var pvElf = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
pvElf.text = "100";
pvElf.fontSize = 45;
pvElf.position = CGPoint(x:370, y:600)
pvElf.zPosition = 2
addChild(pvElf)
```

I want pvElf to be an int but I don't find an SKIntNode or anything else. Because I want to decrease this number when I do an action. But if this is a label I can't.
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply update the label's `text` with the `Int` (converted to a `String`).

```
let someInt = 4
pvElf.text = "\(someInt)"
```

Comment: Obvious ! Thank you ! ^^